# Why did the d.product cant get the value of p.product?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("SELECT  d.detail_id, p.product_name,p.product_price, d.quantity, d.subtotal, p.product_id
    FROM    order_detail AS d, product_list AS p, order_tbl AS r
    WHERE   d.order_id = r.or_id
    AND     d.product_id = p.product_id //---this is the problem
    AND     r.or_id = $result[or_id]
    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider upgrading your PHP and switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Suggest a JOIN syntax like : `FROM  order_detail AS d LEFT JOIN product_list AS p ON d.product_id = p.product_id LEFT JOIN order_tbl AS r ON   d.order_id = r.or_id WHERE ...`

Comment: isn't working d.product_id can't get the value of p.product_id. please help me.

Comment: If you get an error, please add the error message. If you get the wrong result, please add the wrong and the expected output (and some sample data that you base the expected output on). "this is the problem" is rather unspecific and all we could do is list all 13197 causes that might be a problem problem. The most likely cause of an error would e.g. be that you have no column product_id (but maybe just id or p_id) in your table product_list, and that would be clarified in about 0.2 seconds if you would add the error message.